# How do i add a searchbar through class based view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, searchbar

I am new to django and I am trying to create a simple clone version of [pastebin.com][1] that has only one model with name and content. I have created the searchbar in my root template. But what is the actual Class View to filter only the name and show a list of name and content? `

## Patebin Assesment Project

```
  <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>

  <input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Search"/>


</form>`
```

As I have already said I am very new with django. Here's My model

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=300, blank=False)
    content = models.TextField()
    generated_url = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=10, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("pastebin_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a view to handle the search behavior. There is no such generic view, but it's quite easy to create:

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
        self.results = Post.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(results=self.results, **kwargs)
```

Add your view to your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^search/$', SearchView.as_view(), name='search')
```

And make sure you set the right `action` and `method` attributes to your search form:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'pastebin_app:search' %}">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, It worked absolutely fine. I need to cover a lot of basics, would you please help me with how can implement this SearchView in my "search.html" 
I'm sorry for asking all these noob questions

Comment: @ZeedTanue ```results``` is now available in your template view. Now you can create a loop - ```for result in results```. Then you could display the results in a list or table.